# getting error while importing data from oracle to hdfs

Tags: oracle11g, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have tried this command and got following errors..

**Command:**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:1521:XE --username akash -P --table transactions_Oracle --coloumns "Tid,AccounID,Amount" --hive-import   --hive table akash.Transactions_Oracle -m1
```

**Errors:**

```
16/07/13 00:13:38 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.7.0
Enter password: 
16/07/13 00:13:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
16/07/13 00:13:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --coloumns
16/07/13 00:13:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: Tid,AccounID,Amount
16/07/13 00:13:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --hive-import
16/07/13 00:13:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --hive
16/07/13 00:13:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: table
16/07/13 00:13:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: akash.Transactions_Oracle
16/07/13 00:13:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -m1
```

list-database command is working fine but i am not able to import data from table..

Comment: its **columns** in the command not coloumns.

Comment: thanks dev.. now top three are down but i still have last four as Unrecognized argument..

Comment: It's `--hive-table` not --hive table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper syntax is:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:1521:XE --username akash -P --table transactions_Oracle --columns "Tid,AccounID,Amount" --hive-import --hive-table akash.Transactions_Oracle -m 1`

You wrote `coloumns` instead of `columns`, `--hive table` instead of `--hive-table` and `m1` instead of `m 1`

Check drill [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal) to understand meaning of various tags in the import command.